# How to determine the number of elements in a group

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given the universal exponent of n, how do you find the number of elements in $U(n)$ of order $\lambda(n)$?
I understand how to use the multiplicative rule but cannot figure out how to directly show the orders. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is "universal exponent"?

Comment: And what is $\lambda(n)$?

Comment: @JCAA:  cf. [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function); that $\lambda$ is a universal exponent of a group $G$ with identity $e$ means $a^\lambda=e$ for all $a\in G$; I suspect that $U(n)$ here is the group of invertible elements modulo $n$

Comment: And the "universal exponent"?  I also suspect  that $U(n)$ has nothing to do with the unitary group. So what is that?

Comment: Yes so say I calculated the Carmichael function of 6300, now I need to find the number of elements in U(6300) of order lambda(6300)

Comment: I set U(6300) = Z(2^2) x Z(3^2) x Z(5^2) x Z(7) Now I need to find the orders of each group which I cannot figure out how to do..

Comment: $U(n)$ is the multiplicative group of invertible elements modulo $n$?

Comment: You can do this one prime at a time (for every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $U(n)$, find the number of elements in it of maximal order; multiply the answers together). One needs more information than $\lambda(n)$ itself to do this calculation, though: $\lambda(4)=\lambda(8)=\lambda(24)=2$, but the number of elements of order $2$ in $U(4)$ is $1$, in $U(8)$ is $3$, and in $U(24)$ is $7$.